# Test existence of JSON value in JavaScript Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have an array of JSON objects like so:

```
var myArray = [
  {name:'foo',number:2},
  {name:'bar',number:9},
  {etc.}
]
```

How do I detect if myArray contains an object with name="foo"?

Comment: [Those are not JSON objects](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, you should use each at the very least for readability instead of map.  And for performance, you should break the each once you've found what you're looking for, no reason to keep looping:

```
var hasFoo = false;
$.each(myArray, function(i,obj) {
  if (obj.name === 'foo') { hasFoo = true; return false;}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for(var i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) { 
   if (myArray[i].name == 'foo') 
        alert('success!') 
 }
```

Comment: Don't use `for...in` to loop over an array.

Answer (score 1):

With this:

```
$.each(myArray, function(i, obj){
   if(obj.name =='foo')
     alert("Index "+i + " has foo");
});
```

Cheers

Comment: `Array.prototype.each` does not exists. Either you mean `$.each` from jQuery or `Array.prototype.forEach` which is only supported by newer browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
var hasFoo = false;
$.map(myArray, function(v) {
  if (v.name === 'foo') { hasFoo = true; }
});
```

Comment: curious, why map instead of each?

Comment: I just happened to be messing around with the new jQuery 1.6 map on objects and so this was the first thing that came to mind.  Can't imagine there's a performance difference, just need to get over the sorrow of return values being lost to the ether.

Comment: won't somebody think of the poor orphans!

Comment: The disadvantage is that you can not terminate the looping earlier (as opposed to `each`).